# Do the common people of the galaxy know or care that Palpatine is a Sith Lord?

Tags: star-wars

After Palpatine declares the first Empire Day and creates the Galactic Empire, the common people seem to believe his lie that the Jedi staged a rebellion against the Republic. Based on the Senate's reaction in Ep 3 (especially the novelization), it seems like people are loving the idea of Palpatine becoming an Emperor/dictator for life.

But do they know that Palpatine is a Sith Lord? If so, do they care?

Do the common people even know what a Sith Lord is? Does this answer change based on location (i.e. Deep Core vs. Core vs. Outer Rim)?